# JSF2 preRenderComponent is called always when f:ajax is executed

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, initializer, postconstruct

I have an JSF page backed by NewsBean.java which has `<f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{newsBean.init}" />` as bean initializer.

There is a button at the bottom of the page for sending comments which has:
`<f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render="@form" listener="#{newsBean.sendComment}" />` and is surrounded by an `<h:form>`. When button is clicked, `NewsBean.init()` is always called.

My bean scope is view. Is this a valid behavior (calling always init())? How can I prevent always calling `init()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `preRender` listener is always invoked on pre render event, regardless of if it's an initial request or a postback request. Every single request has a render response phase, regardless of if it's a normal request or ajax request. So this behaviour is by specification. You need to check yourself in the listener method if it's a postback request or not by checking [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29).

```
public void sendComment() {
    if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `<f:event type="preRenderXxx">` (where `Xxx` can be `View` or `Component`) is by the way in essence a "workaround approach" for the functional requirement of being able to invoke a bean action method after the view parameters are been processed on the initial request. In the upcoming JSF 2.2 a new `<f:viewAction>` tag will be introduced which should do exactly the job as intented:

```
<f:viewAction action="#{newsBean.sendComment}" />
```

This tag supports an `onPostback` attribute which already defaults to `false`:

```
<f:viewAction action="#{newsBean.sendComment}" onPostback="false" />
```

JSF 2.2 will be released the first quart of 2012. Snapshot releases of JSF 2.2 are currently already available.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. Perfect answer, as always.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `<f:event>` tag is put inside the `<h:form>` tag. Hence, when you click the ajax button, it re-render the whole `<h:form>` component which results in the preRenderComponent event being triggered again.

I think what you should use is [PreRenderViewEvent](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/event/PreRenderViewEvent.html).